# Azure CosmosDB view partition data

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Does anyone know how to check what kind of data is on a certain partition in Azure Cosmos/MongoDB ?

I have one partition exceeding the storage limit, but I can't figure out why. I have one collection, with around 70 partitions. All of the partitions are 3.5GB or less, but one partition is 10GB, causing problems as it exceeds the maximum amount of data.

Yesterday, I removed for about 15% of the data for that partition, but it still claims to be on 10GB.

[image]

How can I check which documents are residents of the particular partition?

Comment: Sorry,not sure what obstacles did you met? Query the documents by the partition -key , any results? Are the 15% saved data actually in the particular partition?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "Query the documents by the partition -key". Is -key a parameter or something? Or do you mean, use a where clause where the 'where' is the partition key? Because the latter we use, that's why we use partitioning. I'm now doubting if the 15% is indeed actually in that partition. That is why I want to see more data within a certain partition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rens Groenveld,firstly,I'd say sorry for the misunderstanding in my comment. After observing your screenshot, combining this [blog](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1255129/What-the-Shard-Partitioning-Azure-Cosmos-DB-with-t), the partition key(in 2nd pic) is for logical partition and the partition name(in 3rd pic) is for physical partition.

> You specify the partition key to create a logicalpartition that
>   guarantees to keep items with the same hash of the key together.
>   Cosmos DB manages the physical partitions based on needs. In the
>   portal, you can see that although we have a few dozen partition keys,
>   there are only a handful of partitions.

You could know the differences between logical partition and physical partition from this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data).

> Unlike logical partitions, physical partitions are an internal
>   implementation of the system. You can't control their size, placement,
>   the count, or the mapping between the logical partitions and the
>   physical partitions. However, you can control the number of logical
>   partitions and the distribution of data and throughput by choosing the
>   right partition key.

Back to your issue, your logical partitioned data is keep together logically, cosmos db would balance them physically which we can't get involved. Data for the same logical partition maybe not reside on the same physical partition. I assumed that's the reason you remove the data does't save the size. I suggest you getting touch with Azure Cosmos DB Team to see what they can do with your physical partition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From the screenshot I can see there is only one logical partition on the physical partition, so I expect it to shrink when I remove data. I think there might still be in buffers in Azure that keeps data coming in or something. I'll have to contact Microsoft indeed :) thanks for your help